# Diagonalising a matrix (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Diagonalise the following matrix $$
A =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -2 & 0 \\
0 &-1& 0 \\
0 & -4 & -1
\end{array} } \right]
$$

What i tried

I know the formula for the diagonal matrix is $D=P^{-1}AP$ where $P$ is the eigenvector. To find the eigenvector i first need to find the eigenvalues which gives $\lambda=1$ or $\lambda=-1$ To find the corresponding eigenvector for $\lambda=1$, i need to find

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1- \lambda& -2 & 0 \\
0 &-1- \lambda& 0 \\
0 & -4 & -1- \lambda
\end{array} } \right]
$$

By subsituting  $\lambda=1$ i got $$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 &-2& 0 \\
0 & -4 & -2
\end{array} } \right]\left( \begin{array}{c}
x_{1}  \\
 x_{2}\\
 x_{3}\end{array} \right)
=\left( \begin{array}{c}
0  \\
0 \\
0 \end{array} \right)$$

I managed to get $$
P=
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 &0& 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{array} } \right]
$$ but it is not invertible and i cant seem to find $P^{-1}$  Could anyone explain this question. Thanks

Comment: First: $P$ is not an eigenvector, but a matrix. Second: your matrix is for $\lambda = 1$ is wrong. $a_{33} = -2$, not $-1$.

Comment: I edited my matrix. But its still not solvable?

Comment: Sure it is. $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(1,0,0)$ is a solution.

Comment: I got $$
P=
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 &0& 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{array} } \right]
$$ but it is not invertible and i cant seem to find $P^{-1}$ Could u explain. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fact that the first column is all zeros shouldn't really bother you, what it means is that $x_1$ can take any value. From the first row you get $x_2=0$ and then the third row becomes $2x_3=-4x_2=0$, so $x_3=0$ and the desired eigenvector (normalized) is $(1,0,0)$.

Comment: I got $$
P=
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 &0& 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{array} } \right]
$$ but it is not invertible and i cant seem to find $P^{-1}$ Could u explain. Thanks

Comment: The -1 eigenvalue has an algebraic multiplicity of 2 (it's a double root of the polynomial), but a geometric multplicity of 1 (the corresponding eigenspace is of dimension 1, spanned by the single vector (0,0,1)) and hence the matrix cannot be diagonalized indeed.